# Border between multiple background images?

Tags: html, css, web

In CSS I can set multiple background images to appear one after another using the background: attribute, but when these images appear on the page there is no transition and the edge between them looks quite ugly.  Is there a way to implement a shadowed border line between two consecutive backgrounds?

e.g.

```
#main-body{
    background: #222222 url(background.jpg), url(background2.jpg);
}
```

This code will set two images to the background, when one image ends as you scroll down the page the next one immediately begins.  There is no visual transition between the two, it's just two images one after another and doesn't look visually appealing.

Comment: Can you share your code or show what you have tried sofar?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want, but you mention shadowed border, so I assume you want the box-shadow property. Try adding this: `-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);` to the style/css for your images. Look at this link for more information about box-shadow: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle the situation here is to draw borders on the top and bottom of your image with desired color and desired width. You can use any image editor to do this and this will also make your task simpler.